# How to change tabulator Pagination buttons text and position

Tags: tabulator

First part of the question is I want to simply change the original buttons "First", "Prev" and so on to some other text.
here is a [link](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/page) that shows original btns.
My second part of the question is how can i display the pagination in a footer out side the table
such as:

```html
<table></table>
<div class:"footer">
    pagination
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options you can use to change the pagination setup

#### Button Text

If you are looking to change the text, then the localisation system allows you to change any text for any part of the table, for full details see the [Localization Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/localize)

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    locale:"en-gb",
    langs:{
        "en-gb":{
            "pagination":{
                "page_size":"Page Size", //label for the page size select element
                "first":"First", //text for the first page button
                "first_title":"First Page", //tooltip text for the first page button
                "last":"Last",
                "last_title":"Last Page",
                "prev":"Prev",
                "prev_title":"Prev Page",
                "next":"Next",
                "next_title":"Next Page",
            },
        }
    },
});
```

#### Button Position

If you simply want to change the position of the pagination element within the footer you can use CSS. The [Styling Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/style#css-page) contains a full list of classes used for styling the pagination elements.

To move the elements to the left hand side of the footer for example you would ned to use the following CSS:

```css
.tabulator .table-footer{
    text-align:left;
}
```

#### External Footer Element

if you want Tabulator to put the pagination elements into an element outside of the table, then you just need to pass the query selector for the element into the ***footerElement*** property in the table constructor. The [Footer Layout Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/layout#footer) contains full details on this.

In the example below i am assuming you have an element outside the table with an id of "my-footer" that you want the elements to appear in:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    footerElement:"#my-footer",
});
```

Comment: Sorry for asking other question here : about loader element. In the doc, it says that the loader element can be set globally in the options and should be specified as a div with a display style of inline-block. In what property of the option should I put the loader element ? Is the property named loader ? I don't use Ajax loader, I use fetch API for fetching data. Thank in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the first part of the question:

```
 $(".tabulator-paginator").find($(".tabulator-page[title='Next Page']")).text('>');
                    $(".tabulator-paginator").find($(".tabulator-page[title='Last Page']")).text('>>');
                    $(".tabulator-paginator").find($(".tabulator-page[title='First Page']")).text('<');
                    $(".tabulator-paginator").find($(".tabulator-page[title='Prev Page']")).text('<<');
```

As far as the second part tabulator have to keep the footer inside the table for it's javascript(the one the does pagination) to work. Hopefully in future updates it would let us do that, as it would provide more ability to custom the css.

Comment: It is inadvisable to try and manipulate elements inside the table

Comment: and has a localization system to allow setting of all text in the table